# Инкапсулировать названия БД

Tags: sql, база-данных

Предположим есть две базы, BD1 и BD2. В процедурах, функциях, триггерах бывает обращения к другой базе. К примеру в процедуре базы BD1 вызывается BD2..Table1.
Таких баз три вида: база для разработки - база для тестирования - продакшен база. У них разные названия и соответственно приходится везде переименовать к примеру, BD2 на BD2_dev и пр.
Это очень затрудняет сравнения, слияния и пр.
Можно как-то создать синоним на БД или что-то похожее?
Подскажите, пожалуйста, хорошую практику решения такой задачи.

Comment: Базы данных должны быть независимыми. Сделайте из них одну - и проблема исчезнет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запустите три независимых инстанса баз. Например, на разных портах. Или в разных `LXC` или там модных `docker` контейнерах каких. В конечном итоге вам это делать всё равно придётся - например, чтобы проверить работу на новой версии СУБД перед обновлением всего прода.

Сразу же всё различие кода сводится только к разным параметрам подключения к базе.